# Uneven UV-unwrapping

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Recently got back to trying to learn 3D-modeling, last time i gave up because of the UVs never working, or never working as i expected them to anyway.

So, whats the problem here? why are the UVs uneven? Why not like in the 2nd picture?

[image]

[image: Picture of the problem]

[image: I expected something like this]

Comment: Each unwrap method is best in different situations. Select your island of faces (click on a face > Ctrl-L to select the part bordered with seams) and unwrap using *Follow active quads* > *Length Average*. Although a normal Unwrap should work for you also if your mesh has nice right angles.

Comment: It looks like this when i use the method you suggested, i also feel a normal unwrap should work in this case, its a really simple model, with only 90degree angles..https://i.imgur.com/IwetHtu.png

Comment: The pastebin file seems to have no objects in it.  Can you check to make sure you have the right file and add it to your question?

Comment: BTW, there is a website for adding blend files to questions:Grab the URL of the question
Go to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/
Select the blend file
Add the url of the question
Grab the url that results
Go back to the question and edit it

Add the new url to the bottom of the post

Comment: Added a new link to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose another unwraping method(just after unwrap operation at the bottom left corner of the 3d View). 'Conformal' seems to work fine.

[image]

Also, you should not use 2.80 version. It is not released yet. Bugs are still very much expected in the beta version so it will most likely cause various problems for you especially while you are learning and might not understand what should be happening and what might be happening because of bugs. At least keep this in mind because some things are going to work in ways you are not even supposed to expect in this version because it is still experimental.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks. I havent even seen that button before.